# Excel: Remove part of cell (String) based on another cell (String)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns/cells that look like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Word123 | Word1 Word12 Word123 Word1234 |

My question:
How can I remove the "Word123" (value of Column A) inside Column B so that the value of Column B looks like this:
Word1 Word12 Word1234

Note that in Column B there is always one space character betweens these values and I have a lot of rows that need this kind of processing.

I have tried using the SUBSTITUTE Function but that doesnt seem to do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(B2,," "),TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER(x,COUNTIFS(A2,x)=0)))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked greatly. Thanks a lot Harun!!

Comment: @Jessy Glad to know. I would suggest you to use `FILTERXML()`. This is more suite for this case. Try- `=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.!= '"&A2&"']"))`.

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTITUTE works fine too... But you need to use some extra spaces to separate the strings clearly:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" " & B1 & " " ; " " & A1 & " " ; " "))
```